# read the windows event log by particular Source

Tags: c#, .net, event-log

How can i read the windows event log by particular Source, Date time and category??

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [EventLog Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx).

> **EventLog** lets you access or customize
>   Windows event logs, which record
>   information about important software
>   or hardware events. Using EventLog,
>   you can read from existing logs, write
>   entries to logs, create or delete
>   event sources, delete logs, and
>   respond to log entries. You can also
>   create new logs when creating an event
>   source.

Answer (score 0):

You could use additional software called "[Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en)"

Comes with an API you can use, check the help file once installed :)

Comment: A sample code using log parser would make your answer extremly helpful. Even though I'd rather use internal System.Diagnostics to read the log - Somebody else might find this useful. If you update i will +1

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is mighty old, but I spent a good deal of time today building a solution to this so I thought I would share:

```
        Dim myEventLogEntryCollection As EventLogEntryCollection = New EventLog("Application", System.Environment.MachineName).Entries

        Dim myEventLogEntryArray(myEventLogEntryCollection.Count - 1) As EventLogEntry

        myEventLogEntryCollection.CopyTo(myEventLogEntryArray, 0)

        Dim QueryLog As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of EventLogEntry) = myEventLogEntryArray.AsQueryable

        QueryLog = QueryLog.Where(Function(i As EventLogEntry) i.Source = "MyParticularSourceName")

        For Each Entry As EventLogEntry In QueryLog

            '... your code goes here

        Next

        myEventLogEntryCollection = Nothing
        myEventLogEntryArray = Nothing
```

Hope it helps others!